# Architecture with SQL server and activemq

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, activemq-classic

I have SQL Server 2012 and ActiveMQ (JMS server). SQL Server has a trigger to send message to ActiveMQ whenever there is an insert into a database table. We have a requirement that we should not lose any messages. So there is a chance to have ActiveMQ go down, in this case we should not lose messages. How can I handle this situation? I heard about clustering, will this work for us?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server and ActiveMQ must be enrolled in a distributed transaction, using an [XA coordinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA). See [Supporting XA Transactions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753563%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [ActiveMQ: How do Transactions Work](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-transactions-work.html). Nothing else will work because SQL Server can rollback *after* the trigger had run and in this case the ActiveMQ `send` must also be rolled back.